# How to call the par(), settings embed an object in R?

Tags: r

Before considering your answer, I would like to correct my question:
And regarding your question: “ I'm curious why, though, you are setting the parameters after plotting vice before? “ Actually, I just forgot mentioning something. The correct order is this:

Using the data again:

```
    dose <- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60) 
    drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60) 
    drugB <- c(15, 18, 25, 31, 40)
```

1st:run: `plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red"`  (it is just for  a self checking mechanism. I mean I am proving myself that  first, I am generating the plot with default R settings)(Plot_1)
[image]

2nd_run: `opar.1<-par(pin=c(5, 3), lwd=2, cex=1.5)`

3rd_run: `plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red")` (same plot with opar.1 setting, so I compare first plot and second plot)(Plot_2)
[image]

4th_run: `par(opar.1)` (with the intention of resetting the opar.1 settings.)

5th_run: `plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red")` (And I am seeing that my third plot is the same with my first plot. Hence, this proves par(opar.1) command reset opar.1 settings and turn it to the default settings.)(Plot_3 same as Plot_1)
[image]

But, 5th_ when I run `opar.1` and then 6th_run `plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red"`, I am not getting a plot as the same as plot_2.
In conclusion,I was wondering if am I getting wrong by thinking “`opar.1<-par(pin=c(5, 3), lwd=2, cex=1.5)`” command store the “`par(pin=c(5, 3), lwd=2, cex=1.5)`” settings and even if I use “`par(opar.1)`” command just after  “`opar.1<-par(pin=c(5, 3), lwd=2, cex=1.5)`” command and reset the `opar.1` settings, by running “opar.1” I can load “`par(pin=c(5, 3), lwd=2, cex=1.5)`” settings?

Comment: there are examples in `?par` that demonstrate how to do this correctly

Answer (score 1):

There are two mechanisms that come to mind, and though you are starting in the right direction, you're missing the final point(s). I'm curious why, though, you are setting the `par`ameters after plotting vice before? To be useful, you typically need to set them before calling `plot`.

Using your data:

```
dose <- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
drugB <- c(15, 18, 25, 31, 40)
```

1. The first mechanism does not require additional packages:

   ```
   opar.1 <- par(pin = c(5, 3), lwd = 2, cex = 1.5)
   plot(dose, drugA, type = "b", pch = 19, lty = 2, col = "red") 
   par(opar.1)
   ```

   One risk of doing it this way is that, before the restorative call to `par`, if any code fails (causing a `stop` or other early-exit from a function), your second `par` command may not be called. *In a function* (not command-line), this problem can be avoided with something like the following, specifically provided (as @rawr mentioned) in `?par`:

   ```
   opar.1 <- par(pin = c(5, 3), lwd = 2, cex = 1.5)
   on.exit(par(opar.1))
   plot(dose, drugA, type = "b", pch = 19, lty = 2, col = "red")
   ```

   (This only does what you want when executed in a function ... on the command-line, you'll need the first instance of calling `par` directly.)
2. Using the `withr` package:

   ```
   library(withr)
   message('## before with_par')
   # ## before with_par
   str(par(c('pin', 'lwd', 'cex')))
   # List of 3
   #  $ pin: num [1:2] 5.76 5.16
   #  $ lwd: num 1
   #  $ cex: num 1
   with_par(list(pin = c(5, 3), lwd = 2, cex = 1.5), {
     plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red")
     message('## inside with_par')
     str(par(c('pin', 'lwd', 'cex')))
   })
   # ## inside with_par
   # List of 3
   #  $ pin: num [1:2] 5 3
   #  $ lwd: num 2
   #  $ cex: num 1.5
   message('## after with_par')
   # ## after with_par
   str(par(c('pin', 'lwd', 'cex')))
   # List of 3
   #  $ pin: num [1:2] 5.76 5.16
   #  $ lwd: num 1
   #  $ cex: num 1
   ```

   The `message` and `str` calls for before, inside, and after `with_par` are to demonstrate that the parameters are only changed inside the code block, so this is relatively safe both in functions and on the command-line.

Both methods provide identical `par`-adjusted plots.

Comment: Does this help at all? It's courteous to approve or discuss further (e.g., if not working for you).